# Size of the embeded PDF document in Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to embed a pdf document in a Rmarkdown document generated by KnitR using `\includepdf`. It works but included documents are very small:

[image: example of the resized pdf I get]

The reproducible example below:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
url = 'https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf'
download.file(url, 'gg.pdf')
```
\includepdf[pages=-]{gg.pdf}
````

Is there a way to resize the inserted document to its original size?
I've found a possible solution but I don't know how to implement it in KnitR:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264383/pdfpages-does-not-correctly-scale-inserted-pdf-pages

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using Rmarkdown 1.10, and either pandoc 1.17.2 or pandoc 2.2.1 on Linux. What are you using?

Comment: I just had the same issue and putting `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio}` directly before `\includepdf` resolved it.