# Embed a pdf in a R Markdown file and adapt pagination

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, r-markdown

I am finishing my PhD, and I need to embed some papers (in pdf format) in somewhere in the middle of my R Markdown text.

When converting the R Markdown into PDF, I would like those PDF papers to be embed in the conversion.

However, I would like those PDF papers to be also numbered according to the rest of the Markdown text.

How can I do it?

---

UPDATE: New error

By using `\includepdf`, I get this error:

```
output file: Tesis_doctoral_-_TEXTO.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.695 \includepdf
                 [pages=1-10, angle=90, pagecommand={}]{PDF/Paper1.pdf} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12157 strings out of 495028
 174654 string characters out of 6181498
 273892 words of memory out of 5000000
 15100 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 40930 words of font info for 89 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 31i,4n,35p,247b,342s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Error: Failed to compile Tesis_doctoral_-_TEXTO.tex. See Tesis_doctoral_-_TEXTO.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

---

EXAMPLE of the R Markdown code

````
---
title: Histología dental de los homininos de la Sierra de Atapuerca (Burgos, España)
  y patrón de estrategia de vida
author: "Mario Modesto-Mata"
date: "20 September 2018"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: pygments
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
  html_document: default
csl: science.csl
bibliography: references.bib
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

```{r opciones_base_scripts, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
library(captioner)
tabla_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Tabla")
figura_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Figura")
anx_tabla_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Anexo Tabla")
```

# Resumen

Los estudios de desarrollo dental en homínidos han sido sesgados involuntariamente en especies pre-Homo y algunos especímenes Homo tempranos, que representan la condición primitiva con tiempos de formación dental más rápidos, respetan a los Neandertales posteriores y a los humanos modernos, que comparativamente tienen tiempos de formación más lentos.

## PDF Article

\includepdf[pages=1-22, pagecommand={}]{PDF/Paper1.pdf}

## Bayes

El desarrollo dental relativo se evaluó empleando un enfoque estadístico bayesiano (31).
````

[This is the link to download the PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M8QkRZtTBEbmd_qjRxO79D533tQqv2wt/view?usp=sharing)

---

NEW IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/how-to-add-a-page-number-to-the-included-pdf-pages?

Comment: I am getting an error. I updated the question to include the error.

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{pdfpages}` to the preamble of the resulting LaTeX files. There are several ways to do this, depending on which template you use.

Comment: I guess you refer editing the YAML in Markdown. If this is the case, what lines should I add there?

Comment: One possibility: `header-includes:<new-line>
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}`

Comment: @RalfStubner  Ok then. I am getting closer. I edited the YAML code by adding your code. And now I don't get any error. However, the PDF paper I would like to embed appears blank. When I write this in the middle of the text `\includepdf[pages=1-10, pagecommand={}]{PDF/Paper1.pdf}
`, those 10 pages (supposedly from the PDF article) appears in blank. What's wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise it is impossible to debug such issues.

Comment: @RalfStubner I have just added an example. See the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to remove a few things from your example, but after that it worked without problems:

```
---
title: Histología dental de los homininos de la Sierra de Atapuerca (Burgos, España)
  y patrón de estrategia de vida
author: "Mario Modesto-Mata"
date: "20 September 2018"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: pygments
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    keep_tex: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
  html_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
---


# Resumen

Los estudios de desarrollo dental en homínidos han sido sesgados involuntariamente en especies pre-Homo y algunos especímenes Homo tempranos, que representan la condición primitiva con tiempos de formación dental más rápidos, respetan a los Neandertales posteriores y a los humanos modernos, que comparativamente tienen tiempos de formación más lentos.

## PDF Article

\includepdf[pages=1-22, pagecommand={}, scale = 0.9]{Paper1.pdf}

## Bayes

El desarrollo dental relativo se evaluó empleando un enfoque estadístico bayesiano (31).
```

Result:

[image]

BTW, for something like a thesis I would use `bookdown`, since this gives you cross-referencing etc.

If that does not work for you, I suggest first looking at plain LaTeX, i.e. does the following LaTeX document work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
foo

\includepdf[pages=1-22, pagecommand={}, scale = 0.9]{Paper1.pdf}

bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am still finding blank pages when including `\includepdf[pages=1-22, pagecommand={}, scale = 0.9]{PDF/Paper1.pdf}` Could it be related with the removal of some YAML lines?

Comment: @antecessor Could be. Did you try my example? BTW, I added `scale` since the page number was uncomfortably close to the footer of the included PDF.

Comment: I copied/pasted it with this result: `processing file: prueba.Rmd
output file: prueba.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS prueba.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output prueba.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 4 --template /home/mario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --number-sections --highlight-style pygments --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' 

Output created: prueba.pdf`

Comment: @antecessor I don't see any error message in your output. Do you have `Paper1.pdf` in the same directory as `prueba.Rmd`?

Comment: Yes. See the image added in my question.

Comment: @antecessor There is a small grey rectangle on that empty page  which reminds me of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198354/size-of-the-embeded-pdf-document-in-rmarkdown. How about `scale = 10` instead of `scale = 0.9`?

Comment: Uhmmm, interesting. I did not realize those were tiny pages of the PDF. However, whan changing the scale to 10, it makes no difference.

Comment: @antecessor odd, see updated answer for a debugging possibility.

Comment: I tried with my personal computer and it worked nicely. My working station might have been somehow unupdated.

Comment: @antecessor so what was the issue? Was `pdfpages` too old? what did you update

Comment: I did nothing. I simply tried in other computer with the last version of Linux Mint and all the packages of Latex.

Comment: @antecessor Can you add the used versions on the two machines? I would say: R, rmarkdown, knitr, RStudio (correlates with bundled pandoc), TeX distribution.