# how to add a (multipage) pdf to rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))

pdf("P://mychart.pdf")
print(mydata2$myplot)
dev.off()
```

The code above will output a pdf with two pages. How can I show these two pages on my `rmarkdown` document?

Using

````
---
title: "crazy test"
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = 'h')
```


ttt

## this is a test!!

```{r label, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = "caption"}
knitr::include_graphics(path = "P://mychart.pdf")
```
````

will only show the first page of the `pdf`! Where is the other chart? :(

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make one pdf for each graph (numbered) and then add them to the markdown document through a loop?

Comment: no but assume you get the `pdf` from outside. you only have the pdf. how would you do it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example (what package does nest come from?). The `include_graphics` function doesn't seem to support multipage pdfs as is. Try splitting your pdf with [staplr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/staplr/staplr.pdf) (possibly in a chunk with echo=FALSE) and then including the resulting graphs in a `include_graphics` loop.

Comment: hold on let me add the packages. sorry about that

Comment: can you run it now? do you mind posting your solution with `staplr`? sounds really promising!!! thanks

Comment: You could use the LaTeX package `pdfpages`, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482385/8416610.

Comment: hi Ralf! I see but how could i make it work in a rmarkdown chunk?!

Comment: @RalfStubner that works! you do mind posting your solution? its pretty neat in the context of `rmarkdown`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One can use `pdfpages` to include multiple pages from a PDF file at once. However, these are included on separate pages. While it is possible to add page numbers, you cannot easily put these images into a `figure` environment. Fortunately, `\includegraphics` has an option to use individual pages from a PDF. Unfortunately, `knitr::include_graphics`
does not allow passing additional arguments to `\includegraphics`.

Here both possibilities:

````
---
title: "crazy test"
output:
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = 'h')
```


```{r, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))

pdf("mychart.pdf")
print(mydata2$myplot)
dev.off()
```


## this is a test!!

Only first page

```{r label, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = "caption"}
knitr::include_graphics(path = "mychart.pdf")
```

All pages but w/o caption and taking a full page

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2,pagecommand={}]{mychart.pdf}

Alternative, using explicit LaTeX commands.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=0.5\linewidth]{mychart.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.5\linewidth]{mychart.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:test} Test.}
\end{figure}
````

One could also put these into a R chunk with `cat()` and `result = 'asis'`. However, the options for setting caption etc. are still not used.

Comment: pretty cool. essentially i can add to markdown any kind of crazy latex command as long as i import the packages

Comment: it would be nice that `include_graphics` includes a `page_num` argument so that we can choose which page to show

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Including raw LateX is possible due to pandoc's [raw_tex](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_tex) extension. Adding a specific option for individual pages in a PDF would be strange, since it would not make sense in many use cases of the command. However, a more generic "pass these additional arguments" might be worthwhile.

Comment: hello i actually disagreee. In many cases one only wants to add a given table in a paper, or part of the appendix, or a single chart. In that case, including just the page wanted in necessary. Otherwise one has to manually extract the page with acrobat, and then use the command. which is really cumbersome if you have many pdfs... :) thanks again!

Comment: on a side note, using `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={},scale = 0.9]` shows my chart in the `pdf`, but the chart is SO SMALL I can barely see it :) any ideas what is the issue?

Comment: No idea, but you are the third person reporting this, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480647/embed-a-pdf-in-a-r-markdown-file-and-adapt-pagination and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198354/size-of-the-embeded-pdf-document-in-rmarkdown

Comment: one more reason to have this `num_page` arg in `include_graphics`... :)

Comment: It includes only white pages. Could you provide an minimal working example with the distracting R code?

Comment: @user3072843 What includes only white pages? What example are you missing?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the Rmd solution with staplr. Please be advised that you need to install pdftk for split_pdf to work

````
---
title: "crazy test"
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = 'h')
```

## Split pdf

```{r}
staplr::split_pdf("mychart.pdf", output_directory = ".", prefix = "mychart_")
```

## Add pdfs

```{r label, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = c("caption 1", "caption 2"), echo = FALSE}
flist <- list.files()
mychart_files <- flist[grep("mychart_", flist)]
knitr::include_graphics(mychart_files)
```
````

Also, include graphics doesn't work in a loop. But it accepts multiple paths, so that works out well.

Comment: Yes, it can be problematic... particularly on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04). Ralf's suggestion seems to be a possible solution, using pdflatex.

Answer (score 2):

**knitr** has a specific chunk option called `out.extra` that allows to pass options to the `\includegraphics` command. See about this option in [knitr doc](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots).

This means it can be used to page the option `page`. Using the example above, you could do

````r
---
title: "crazy test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = 'h')
```


```{r, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mydata <- tibble(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))

pdf("mychart.pdf")
print(mydata2$myplot)
dev.off()
```

Only first page

```{r label, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = "caption"}
knitr::include_graphics(path = "mychart.pdf")
```

second page

```{r label2, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = "caption", out.extra="page=2"}
knitr::include_graphics(path = "mychart.pdf")
```
````